# Spring MVC Unable to run standalone jar

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I'm quite new to Java EE and relative things, so I do not use Maven or any other tools to build projects (Maven dependencies are used, but not build options and export), just Eclipse->Export->Runnable Jar.
And it worked nice.

I have app with embedded Jetty and Spring MVC. In Eclipse Debug it works fine, but after exporting into jar I get:

> WARN  PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver:602 java.io.FileNotFoundException: URL [rsrc:myapp/Web/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: rsrc:myapp/Web/

The resource is in the jar.
I'm using Annotations, and it's mentioned in stack trace, but, Spring tries to load file resource, insted of classpath.

> at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:212)
>           at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:52)

Full stack trace:

```
at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:212)
    at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:52)
    at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getFile(UrlResource.java:212)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.doFindPathMatchingFileResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:598)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResourcePatternResolver.doFindPathMatchingFileResources(ServletContextResourcePatternResolver.java:92)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.findPathMatchingResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:419)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.getResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:273)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getResources(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1159)
    at org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext.getResources(GenericApplicationContext.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:270)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:248)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:262)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:226)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:163)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:775)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1252)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:710)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at myapp.Web.WebServer.startJetty(WebServer.java:55)
    at myapp.Web.WebServer.Start(WebServer.java:41)
    at Main.main(Main.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
```

Web conf:

```
EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"myapp.Web"})
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ServletContextAware {

    private ServletContext _servletContext;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
//      configurer.enable();
        configurer.enable("jsp");
    }

    @Bean
    public TilesViewResolver tilesViewResolver(){
//      UrlBasedViewResolver ret = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        TilesViewResolver ret = new TilesViewResolver();
        ret.setViewClass(org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView.class);
        ret.setOrder(org.springframework.core.Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return ret;
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
        bean.setOrder(2);
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer TilesConfigurer(){
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer ret =
                new org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer();
        ret.setServletContext(_servletContext);
        ret.setDefinitions("/WEB-INF/tile-defs/templates.xml"
                ,"/WEB-INF/tile-defs/definitions.xml");
        ret.setCheckRefresh(true);
        return ret;
    }

    @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public CommonsMultipartResolver getMultipartResolver() {
        return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    }

    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource getMessageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource resource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        resource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
        resource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return resource;
    }

    @Override
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        _servletContext = servletContext;
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-misc</artifactId>
            <version>4.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.javaconfig</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-javaconfig</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.m3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j.adapters</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-beta4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-ftp</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
            <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
            <version>4.10.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsp-2.1</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsp-api-2.1</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api-2.1</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jasper-compiler</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jasper-runtime</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsp-2.1</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsp-api-2.1</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api-2.1</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jasper-compiler</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jasper-runtime</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.0.M1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.0.M1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**UPD**
I've guessed to check ResourceUtils.java:212

```
public static final String URL_PROTOCOL_FILE = "file";
public static File getFile(URL resourceUrl, String description) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Assert.notNull(resourceUrl, "Resource URL must not be null");
    if (!URL_PROTOCOL_FILE.equals(resourceUrl.getProtocol())) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException(
                description + " cannot be resolved to absolute file path " +
                "because it does not reside in the file system: " + resourceUrl);
    }
    try {
        return new File(toURI(resourceUrl).getSchemeSpecificPart());
    }
    catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
        // Fallback for URLs that are not valid URIs (should hardly ever happen).
        return new File(resourceUrl.getFile());
    }
}
```

Comment: May we see your POM file as well?

Comment: If you are going to create an executable JAR, I suggest you take a good look at Spring Boot. It will take away a lot of the pain you are going through :)